# If statement in repeater control

Tags: asp.net, repeater

So depending on if the repeater item has a link or not I want to use a link around an image otherwise I just want to out put link.

Right now I have

```
<asp:Repeater ID="BannerImageRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).CallToActionUrl %>"><img src="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).ImageUrl %>?w=980&h=600" alt="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).AltText %>"/></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

So wanted to add something like

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).CallToActionUrl)

<img src="">
else
<a href=''><img src=""></a>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Would you be willing to use some code-behind coding or do you want to do all this on the aspx page?

Comment: Id like to do in aspx, but either I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two controls, one as a link and the other an image control. Then use code behind to toggle their visibility. An invisible asp.net control is not rendered at all so you should be fine. Change this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="BannerImageRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).CallToActionUrl %>"><img src="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).ImageUrl %>?w=980&h=600" alt="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).AltText %>"/></a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

To this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="BannerImageRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:hyperlink id="yes_link" runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).CallToActionUrl %>"><img src="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).ImageUrl %>?w=980&h=600" alt="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).AltText %>"/></asp:hyperlink>
            <asp:image id="no_link" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).ImageUrl %>?w=980&h=600" alt="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).AltText %>" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

If you need to incorporate client side javascript, assign each control a CssClass and reference that in your script. Let us know how it goes and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="BannerImageRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <% if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).CallToActionUrl)) { %>
<img src="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).ImageUrl %>?w=980&h=600" alt="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).AltText %>"/>
<% } else { %>
        <a href="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).CallToActionUrl %>"><img src="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).ImageUrl %>?w=980&h=600" alt="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).AltText %>"/></a>
<% } %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Tried that doesnt like get errors around the if statement, first the Container which I can fix by including <%@ Import Namespace="System.ComponentModel" %> but then DataItem..it says cannot resolve symbol

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different approach. Also, you can likely use `Eval()` in both your markup and code behind instead of relying on `Container.DataItem`, but I am not following the specific property names.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="BannerImageRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible="<%# GetVisibleImage() %>">
        <a href="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).CallToActionUrl %>">
            <img src="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).ImageUrl %>
                ?w=980&h=600" alt="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).AltText %>"/>
        </a>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible="<%# GetVisibleNoImage() %>">
        <img src="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).ImageUrl %>
                ?w=980&h=600" alt="<%# ((BannerImage)Container.DataItem).AltText %>"/>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In your codebehind:

```
protected bool GetVisibleImage()
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Eval("CallToActionUrl"));
}

protected bool GetVisibleNoImage()
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Eval("CallToActionUrl"));
}
```

Comment: You can also just use a `<asp:HyperLink>` and specify `ImageUrl` along with a `<asp:Image>` control and wire up the `Visible` property of each with similar server side code.

Comment: How is this different from my answer? I'm not trolling your answer or anything, I am actually interested to know what you did differently here. I am still working on my first asp.net site so I am very open to new methods, etc.

Comment: @Lopsided, You are not toggling the visibility (`Visible="<%# GetVisibleImage() %>"` based on a server side bool computation. Also, you can specify an `ImageUrl` property directly on the `<asp:HyperLink>` control.

Comment: Good points. Ahh now I see what you did there (BTW I am a VB programmer), the isnullorempty function returns a true or false which you pull using the <%# GetVisibleImage() %> tag. Well done, sir.

Comment: No worries. You should be able to do the same thing with vb.net. I am doing less and less web forms development but it does have its place. In general, I try to avoid logic in the UI / markup and instead use this technique to get code / server side computational / logical results.

Comment: I'm trying this technique now and for some reason my Visible="<%# getVisible() %>" tag is not calling the getVisible() function. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?