# If statement on aspx

Tags: asp.net, gridview, eval

New to asp.net ...

In `DataList`, `ItemTemplate`, I would like to check if `value ("Exchange")` in the DB is true.

If it's true I'd like to display a label with the text "True".

Please note Exchange is stored in the DB as

Was thinking about this, but no success yet.

```
 <%#Eval("Exchange").ToString() == "True" ? "<asp:Label ID=\"Exchange\" runat=\"server\" Text=\"True">   </asp:Label>":""%>
```

Can anyone help?

Many thanks

Comment: Please check these links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289917/eval-if-statement-in-repeaterd
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073606/if-statement-in-repeater-control

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063436/if-statement-in-aspx-page is the top link returned by Google for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asp.net way of doing what you want to do is this.

```
<asp:Label ID="Exchange" runat="server" Text="True" Visible='<%# Eval("Exchange").ToString() == "True" %>' />
```

If `Exchange` is bool you do not require the `ToString` call

```
<asp:Label ID="Exchange" runat="server" Text="True" Visible='<%# Eval("Exchange") %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to try it, but you can write the if for the text property. This should display a label with no text (therefore nothing visible) if the Eval("Exchange") returns something other than "True"

```
<asp:Label ID="Exchange" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Exchange")=="True" ? "True": "" %></asp:Label>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DataReader["Exchange"].ToString()` itself will return a string `"True"` or `"False"` hence you dont need to use any condition for this:

```
    <asp:Label ID=\"Exchange\" runat=\"server\" Text=\"<%#Eval("Exchange").ToString()%>\" </asp:Label>
```